# Find out which of my NSButton is pressed

Tags: grid, title, nsbutton

I created a NSButton grid (see picture) and setAction for each NSButton like this:

```
[myButton setAction:@selector(buttonPressed)];

-(void)buttonPressed { //things run here
    NSLog(@"Button pressed!%@", titleString);
}
```

Unfortunately I don´t see how to get the **title** of the **button** which was pressed. I would like to retriev the buttontitle and store it in **titleString** at the beginning of buttonPressed.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created an **IBAction** to get a **sender** what I already tried before without success:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender {
   NSString *titleStr = [sender title]; //getting the btn text
   NSLog(@"Button '%@' pressed!", titleStr);
}
```

The clue ist that buttonPressed must be followed by a colon. Now it works like a charm.

```
[myButton setAction:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
```